# Apex refresh is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

Apex Refresh data-table is not working on LWC. Can anyone please help me what I'm missing below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="slds-p-top_x-large">
                            <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns}
                                draft-values={draftValues} hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                resize-column-disabled="true">
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>

 <div class="slds-size_2-of-2">
                                        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" value="AddParent"
                                            name="AddParent" label="Save" onclick={handleonClickParent}>
                                        </lightning-button>
                                    </div>
```

**JS**

```
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";


@track error;
@track data;

@wire(getParentdetails, { enrollmentName: "a082w000000YUH5AAO" })


getContacts(response) {
console.log("data -->" + response);
this.wiredDataRefresh = response;
const data = response.data;
const error = response.error;
if (data) {
  this.data = data;
} else if (error) {
  this.error = error;
}
}

 handleonClickParent() {
 return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);
}

refreshData() {
return refreshApex(this.wiredDataRefresh);
}
```

**Apex:**

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
public static List<Contact> getParentdetails(Id enrollmentName) {
     return   [select  Id, Firstname, LastName, Email, Phone, Student_Relation__c
              from Contact WHERE Enrollment_Name__c=:enrollmentName];
}
```

Comment: `enrollmentName` is expecting an ID but in your sample you're putting "man"

Comment: You define `refreshData()` but doesn't look like you ever call it elsewhere in your code

Comment: @BrianMiller I have save button in my form, onclick of save button `handleonClickParent` is called. Edited my questions

Comment: Also include that save button code. Could be something simple like the names not matching because of being case sensitive, etc

Comment: Added the save button code

Answer (score 0):

`wiredDataRefresh` is not declared in the js file as per your code snip. Could you see if that is the case?

Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment hence writing my comment as an answer. Sorry for this.